# SAS: how can I find the missed/skipped number in a sequence?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset and one column is the ID column which has a sequential of numbers
Exmaple:
**ID**
1
3
5
6
7
8
10
so it's missing 2, 4 and 9
in SAS how can I code it to find these missed/skipped numbers?
I tried Google, but mostly just missing values, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
data missing_ids;
  set have;
  do id = coalesce(lag(id),0)+1 to id-1;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

These are the features of SAS DATA Step that make this example work:

- DATA Step implicit loop, reads one observation at SET statement
- DO Statement: Iterative, *start* TO *stop*

  - The value of *start* is evaluated before the first execution of the loop
  - The value of *stop* is evaluated (once) before the first execution of the loop
- `LAG(id)` in context of example returns value of `id` from prior observation.  Technically, the LAG<n>() function returns a value from a LIFO queue of <n> items.

  - When at first observation, `LAG(id)` returns missing.
  - `COALESCE` returns first nonmissing value from the list of values passed to it.  That is why `COAELSCE` is used to ensure first *start* is nominally `0+1`
  - `SUM` could also be used because SUM function returns the sum of the nonmissing values

`LAG` can be subtle and should be used inside conditional blocks only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: `SUM` would also work in place of `COALESCE`.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked exactly how I pictured!  I googled "coalesce" and "lag", sort of understand the general functionality, but still having trouble to put your do statement to full understanding, could you explain yt if it's not too much trouble?   thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replicate the example

```
data have;
input id;
cards;
1
3
5
6
7
8
10
;
```

Select the minimum and maximum value of the `id` column into two macro variables `min` and `max` then compute the sequence in the `numbers` table

```
proc sql noprint;
    select min(id), max(id) into :min, :max from have;
quit;

data numbers;
    do id=&min. to &max. by 1;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Get the missing numbers in table `want`

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select id from numbers
    where id not in (select id from have);
quit;
```

```
id
2
4
9
```